# How to turn off auto video preview from playing from Windows 10 Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

When browsing through video files in Windows 10's file explorer, if I linger too long on a file windows pops up a preview and begins playing the file.

How do I disable this feature?

Comment: I've never seen that before. Just curious, what file types auto play?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.